# Can I copy-paste Jupyter Notebook code into a Lambda Handler and keep the same functionality?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I am looking to build an AWS architecture where I upload a .csv file with sales data into Amazon S3. I then want a Lambda function to be triggered using my Python code to clean the data and send it to a "clean" S3 bucket upon arrival.

My current solution involves reading the S3 object in SageMaker and manually running the Jupyter Notebook script, as shown:

```
# Sales data S3 location
input_data_location = 's3://BUCKET_NAME/DIRECTORY/salesdata.csv'

# Read the file
df = pd.read_csv(input_data_location)

# Remove unwanted feature names.
df = df[['timestamp', 'store_num', 'actual_sales', 'manager_generated_forecast']]

# Change timestamp column to datetime object.
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'].str.split(' - ').str[1]) 

# Feature engineering.
df['month_of_year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['timestamp']).month
df['day_of_week'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['timestamp']).dayofweek
df['day_of_year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['timestamp']).dayofyear
df['week_of_month'] = ((pd.DatetimeIndex(df['timestamp']).day-1)//(7))+1
df['day_of_month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['timestamp']).day
df['year_of_sales'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['timestamp']).year

# Set timestamp to index.
df.set_index("timestamp", inplace = True)
```

I am not too familiar with creating Lambda Handlers. Is it possible to simply copy-paste this code into the handler or do I need to make adjustments?

Thanks

Comment: Suggestions that might help you and others seeing your post understand everything in play and maybe find easier way and sort your own issues ...You seem to be mixing terms. For example, in your title, you have 'Jupyter Notebook code'? Meaning Python code you developed inside a Jupyter notebook? Jupyter can have code of a lot of different types, even within the same notebook. Then you have in the post, "manually running the the Jupyter Notebook script". Do you mean stepping through running the Python code in the Jupyter Notebook?  It's important for a couple of reasons:  <to be continued..>

Comment: <continuing>...(1) If you didn't want to have to run that notebook 'manually' you can actually use `jupyter nbconvert` [and run it from the command line](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/5.2.1/execute_api.html#executing-notebooks-from-the-command-line) or use jupytext to trigger executing the enite notebook while on the command line. And (2) because you seem to be making it more difficult by wanting to copy-paste? The block of code you post have would just work fine as a Python script file, ending in `.py` because you aren't using any notebook/IPython specific code or magics.  ....

Comment: <continuing...> That's pure Python in that block. You could use [jupytext](https://jupytext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using-cli.html#command-line-conversion) to convert the corresponding notebook to a `.py` script file and then run it with python. (No need for copy-paste, which is especially nice if all that code was spread out among multiple cells.) That will get you closer to what you'll need to modify, such as discussed [here](https://frankcorso.dev/python-aws-lambda-function.html). Your file to trigger cannot be hardcoded in like you have now because ...

Comment: <continuing...> you'll need to do something like done in the Python code example [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html).